# Chef::remote_file unable to download while doing a kitchen converge

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, test-kitchen

I have the following piece of code to download an installer

```
remote_file '/tmp/apache-tomcat-8.0.23.tar.gz' do
  source 'http://mirror.sdunix.com/apache/tomcat/tomcat-8/v8.0.23/bin/apache-tomcat-8.0.23.tar.gz'
end
```

which when executed using `kitchen converge` gives

```
     =====================================================================   ===========
           Error executing action `create` on resource 'remote_file[/tmp/apache-
tomcat-8.0.23.tar.gz]'
           =====================================================================
===========

           Errno::ENETUNREACH
           ------------------
           Failed to open TCP connection to mirror.sdunix.com:80 (Network is unr
eachable - connect(2) for "mirror.sdunix.com" port 80)
```

Any idea why am I getting this network issue?

Comment: Which VM provider do you use beneath test-kitchen?

Comment: I use Vagrant VIrtualbox

Comment: Can you access internet from your VM? How is your network configured?

Comment: driver:
  name: vagrant
  network:
    - ["private_network", {ip: "192.168.35.35"}]

Comment: You use "private network". Here is a quote from vagrant docs: "These IPs are guaranteed to never be publicly routable, and most routers actually block traffic from going to them from the outside world." https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/private_network.html You have to use "public network" or "forwarded ports".

Answer (score 0):

I guess that the `url` you are using as source for the remote file is not publicly reachable (I can't resolve it), so my bet is that you are missing a proper network configuration in your `kitchen-vagrant` virtual machine. Are you using correct `dns` servers? If you don't need/have them, try updating your `/etc/hosts` file so it contains the address os `http://mirror.sdunix.com/`.